# Get login user's Full Name when login to different domain windows authentication C#

Tags: active-directory, windows-authentication

We have problem like, unable to get the user full name when reading from different domain.

eg: My userName is dom1\jsmith and full name is John Smith. When we deploy the project in dom1 domain, we are able to login and get the full name of the user. When we deploy the project in another domain(dom2) where the user(dom1\jsmith) has login permission, able to access the site but not able to get the full name.

We tried different solutions but didn't work.

```
//output: dom1\jsmith
User.Identity.Name;
//output: dom1\jsmith
string s = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name; 

//output: dom1\jsmith
string sUserName = System.Environment.UserName;  


//output: John Smith in same domain but not able to find identity
 using (var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
    {
        var principal = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, User.Identity.Name);
        if (principal != null)
            var fullName = string.Format("{0} {1}", principal.GivenName, principal.Surname);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the name of the logon domain into the constructor for `PrincipalContext`. So split the `DOMAIN\username` that you have, and use just the domain portion:

```
var split = User.Identity.Name.Split('\\');

using (var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, split[0])) {
     ...
}
```

Although I am surprised it doesn't work as you have it, since it works for me and I log into a different domain than what my computer is joined to. Although in my case, the two domains are in the same AD forest. Maybe that's not the case for you.